# Complex query in django

Tags: django, model

Hay, i have a quite complex query i cant get working in django.

My model is called Car(), and i want to perform this query on it

```
query = "SELECT *, ((ACOS(SIN("+user_lat+" * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS("+user_lat+" * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(("+user_lon+" - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM app_car HAVING distance<='"+miles+"' ORDER BY distance ASC"
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:

my view looks like this

```
def find_cars_within_miles_from_postcode(request, miles, postcode=0):

    # create cursor for RAW query
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Get lat and lon from google
    lat, lon = getLonLatFromPostcode(postcode)

    # Gen query
    query = "SELECT id, ((ACOS(SIN("+lat+" * PI() / 180) * SIN(lat * PI() / 180) + COS("+lat+" * PI() / 180) * COS(lat * PI() / 180) * COS(("+lon+" - lon) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance FROM app_car HAVING distance<='"+miles+"' ORDER BY distance ASC"

    # execute the query
    cursor.execute(query)

    # grab all the IDS form the sql result
    ids = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]

    # find cars from ids
    cars = Car.objects.filter(id__in=ids)

    # return the Cars with these IDS
    return HttpResponse( cars )
```

This returns my cars from x amount of miles, this works well. However the raw query returned how far they were from a certain location, i think the fieldname was 'distance'.

How can i return this field 'distance' with my car objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916953/filter-zipcodes-by-proximity-in-django-with-the-haversine-formula). It covers a geo lookup like you want.

Answer (score 1):

The Django ORM doesn't suppport `HAVING`; drop to DB-API for this.

Answer (score 0):

User raw() method and that SQL query to get Cars objects.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a hard time returning the distance value inside a QerySet object (see [my question on the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275573/django-sort-by-calculated-field)), at least until Django 1.2. The easiest thing is to just move your query into a model manager, but return a Python list instead of a queryset. You might also look at Python's geo library for handling these kinds of queries.

Comment: I was tempted to install the geodjango lib, but it seems over kill. The only geo based tasks I'm going to be doing is the one listed above. Seems django 1.2 isn't far off (due for release next month) i think I'll put development of this segment of my application off until April. Thanks Tom.