# Get all points within certain radius in Django

Tags: django, google-maps

For a Google Maps application, I need to create a query that selects all items in my database that fall within a certain radius from a given latitude/longitude, given the lat/lng of each point. Is there an efficient way to do this in the Django ORM?

The best way I have come up with thus far is to select all points that will fall within a bounding square of that circle (with `__range`) and then call a iterative function on all the selected listings to determine whether they really fall in the circle.

My feeling is there might be a more efficient way - how would you do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Django has [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/) for this

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries

Comment: Nice, that's definitely the best answer. Just for interest sake, any idea how you would solve it efficiently in plain Django?

Comment: you could jsut use a raw query like this post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916953/filter-zipcodes-by-proximity-in-django-with-the-spherical-law-of-cosines

Comment: Is it possible to use GeoDjango's methos in a normal Django application?