# Django and location based app

Tags: python, django, geolocation, geodjango

I'm building a django app that requires to display (on google map) items near the user current location. (ie. the nearest coffee shop kind of request).
I haven't decided how I will capture those items' location in db.
The requirements aren't final but I'm guessing the user will want to sort by distance, etc.
My question is what solution should I look into?
I looked at geodjango but it seems to be an overkill.
Could you please tell me what solution you would use and why?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Take a look over [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use RDBMS like MySQL or postgresql. Then, create your objects (e.g: cafeshops) with latitude and longitude as flout. Get the user's latitude and longitude and look it up via sin and cos functions.

You will need to write a raw sql query to look up objects based on their latitude and longitude.

Read this: http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

Take a look at this: [Filter zipcodes by proximity in Django with the Spherical Law of Cosines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916953/filter-zipcodes-by-proximity-in-django-with-the-spherical-law-of-cosines)

and this: [latitude/longitude find nearest latitude/longitude - complex sql or complex calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234204/latitude-longitude-find-nearest-latitude-longitude-complex-sql-or-complex-calc)

Comment: Wow, such a basic answer, but this gave me the necessary light bulb moment. Thanks!